# How to use big.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, floating-point

From the examples of [big.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big.js) they show this example

```
0.3 - 0.1                              // 0.19999999999999998
x = new Big(0.3)
x.minus(0.1)                           // "0.2"
x                                      // "0.3"

x.div(y).plus(z).times(9).minus('1.234567801234567e+8').plus(976.54321).div('2598.11772')
```

Which is a very simple example. In my case I would like to calculate

```
res = a + (b / c) + (d + 1) / (e * f * g);
```

I cannot see how that can be calculated without introducing 7 temporary variables, which doesn't seam correct.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to calculate the above with big.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this "inside-out", i.e. first convert the parts in the inner parentheses.

For example:

```
const temp1 = b.div(c),
      temp2 = d.plus(1),
      temp3 = e.times(f).times(g),
      temp4 = temp2.div(temp3),
      result = a.plus(temp1).plus(temp4);
```

But you don't actually need those temporary variables. Just take that last expression and inject the definition of the temporary variables, so your expression expands to this:

```
const res = a.plus(b.div(c)).plus(d.plus(1).div(e.times(f).times(g)));
//          a  +  (b  /  c )  +   (d  +  1)  / (e   *   f    *   g )
```

Demo:

```js
const params = [1, 100, 5, 99, 2, 5, 2];

{ // First with native types:
    const [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] = params;
    const res = a + (b / c) + (d + 1) / (e * f * g);
    console.log(res);
}

{ // Then with big.js
    const [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] = params.map(Big);
    const res = a.plus(b.div(c)).plus(d.plus(1).div(e.times(f).times(g)));
    console.log(res.toNumber());
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big.js@6.2.1/big.min.js'></script>
```